# Dependancy of Tesseract OCR accuracy on amount of text in the image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to do OCR on very complex scanned table images. Since the tables are complex, I divide tables to several easy to define layout sub-tables, to proceed further. One thing I noticed if I input just little junk containing single line from the image, Tesseract's accuracy is 100%. But for the whole picture it does not even detect some of those that was detected with 100% accuracy as sole. My question is on why Tesseract is behaving so, and what are possible fixes to this problem?